# Mapping over a JSON array with Argonaut

Tags: scala, scalaz, argonaut

I'm having a hard time slogging through the Argonaut documentation, so I figured I'd just ask for a simple example.

```
val input = """{"a":[{"b":4},{"b":5}]}"""

val output = ??? // desired value: List(4, 5)
```

I can get a cursor down to the array:

```
Parse.parse(input).map((jObjectPL >=> jsonObjectPL("a") >=> jArrayPL)(_))
// scalaz.\/[String,Option[scalaz.IndexedStore[argonaut.Argonaut.JsonArray,
//  argonaut.Argonaut.JsonArray,argonaut.Json]]] =
// \/-(Some(IndexedStoreT((<function1>,List({"b":4}, {"b":5})))))
```

But then what? Am I on the right track? Should I even be using cursors for this?

Edit - Here's some progress, I guess. I've written a decoder for the list:

```
Parse.parse("""[{"b": 4}, {"b": 5}]""")
  .map(_.as(IListDecodeJson(DecodeJson(_.downField("b").as[Int]))))
// scalaz.\/[String,argonaut.DecodeResult[scalaz.IList[Int]]] =
// \/-(DecodeResult(\/-([4,5])))
```

Edit - Slowly starting to put it together...

```
Parse.parse(input).map(_.as[HCursor].flatMap(_.downField("a").as(
  IListDecodeJson(DecodeJson(_.downField("b").as[Int])))))
// scalaz.\/[String,argonaut.DecodeResult[scalaz.IList[Int]]] =
// \/-(DecodeResult(\/-([4,5])))
```

Edit - So I guess my best solution so far is:

```
Parse.parse(input).map(_.as(
  DecodeJson(_.downField("a").as(
    IListDecodeJson(DecodeJson(_.downField("b").as[Int])).map(_.toList)
  ))
))
```

Feels a bit verbose, though.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this pretty nicely with the new-ish [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle) support in Argonaut (I'm using Argonaut master here, since the 6.1 milestones are still on Monocle 0.5):

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import monocle._, Monocle._

val lens =
  Parse.parseOptional ^<-? 
  jObjectPrism        ^|-?
  index("a")          ^<-?
  jArrayPrism         ^|->>
  each                ^<-?
  jObjectPrism        ^|-?
  index("b")          ^<-?
  jIntPrism
```

And then:

```
scala> lens.getAll("""{"a":[{"b":4},{"b":5}]}""")
res0: scalaz.IList[Int] = [4,5]
```

The operators look horrible at first, but you get used to them, and the composed pieces read pretty naturally. And of course since this is a lens there are all kinds of operations that you can use in addition to `getAll`.

Answer (score 0):

This case-classing might not be the way you want to go, but here's my 2 cents.

```
case class B(b: Int)
object B {
  implicit def BCodecJson: CodecJson[B] =
  casecodec1(B.apply, B.unapply)("b")
}

val jsonString = """{"a":[{"b":4},{"b":5}]}"""
val vals: List[Int] = Parse.parseOption(jsonString).map { json: Json =>
    (json -|| List("a")).flatMap(_.as[List[B]].value).getOrElse(Nil).map(_.b)
  }.getOrElse(Nil)
```

I guess that does it.